# Browser feature detection in code base - Am I using ...?

Tags: javascript, css, html, feature-detection

http://caniuse.com/ is a very helpful tool to figure out which browsers/versions support a specific CSS, HTML, JS feature. What about a tool that parses my code and tells me what features I'm actually using? If you have a large codebase, finding out post-hoc which features you're actually using can be very tedious if done manually. How would you go about that?

I'm not asking for feature detection at runtime, I know Modernizr but what I need is the exact opposite of that. A solution to find out which tests I need to add to the Modernizr config.

Comment: Why would you have to detect what features your code base is using? Ideally you should just use feature detection against the browser which is why modernizr exists.

Comment: In order to know what tests to add to modernizr you first need to know what features your codebase is using.

Comment: Maybe if you've been given a large code base from a different team that was browser specific. Youve been tasked with making it cross browser and want a quick overlook of the code to see how many occurrences of browser specific API's are being used?

Comment: Again, perfectly valid and format fitting question that is being closed. And without comments.

Comment: well the best tool is a set of target browsers. e.g if you need to support IE8, take a fresh win7, try your page on IE8 and check where it fails. Then add the feature-detection where it failed.

Comment: A question of a programmer for fellow programmers about a programming problem and possible solutions. Where do you think that could be asked? Well, Stack Overflow of course! That's a really great community for exactly that sort of thing. Oh... but it's also that frustrating place where every other question is closed by zealots.

Answer (score 1):

Modernizr might still help you to get there although you would use it in a different way. You could configure it to detect all features and run that in the set of browsers that your project needs to support. Then do something like

```
if ( ! Modernizr.flexbox ) {
 elem.matchHeight();
}
```

for all of the features and you'll quickly find out which features your codebase is using.