# Detection of features used on a website or codebase

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser-feature-detection

Feature detection and browser detection are almost standard practice in good web development now, but is it possible to do the opposite? Detect the features used on a website and/or codebase?
The thought crossed my mind as I was reading the MDN page on feature detection and thought that I can't be the only one and I was right, but the only other one is [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34942434/browser-feature-detection-in-code-base-am-i-using) and if you visit it, I hope you can see why this isn't helpful. Since the term for detecting if browsers are able to use features is called browser feature detection, I feel it fitting to call it website feature detection.

**How would one go about website feature detection.**

Before someone closes this question for being irrelevant since people will ask "why would you need to do this?" or "why not just do x" First of all, I don't think a question can't be asked because there isn't a stated real world use case for it **yet**, but to those who think they should:

- (Stated by ste2425 on the linked post) You've been given a large code base from a different team that was browser specific. You've been tasked with making it cross browser and want a quick overlook of the code to see how many occurrences of browser specific API's are being used.
- (Stated by markus on the linked post) In order to know what tests to add to modernizr you first need to know what features your codebase is using.
- General curiosity of what features a website or codebase uses

Comment: if your developing then add a linter plugin like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15702796/scan-javascript-for-browser-compatibility

Comment: I didn't know about that, so thank you, but I am looking for a script or method that can be used more generally.